# Reading json string from socket

Tags: c#, java, sockets

I have java server that I am writing the server reads command from clients,

the client written in C# sends command via socket in the form of json string.
The command looks like this

```
{
 "command": "blah",
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value3",
 "key3": "value4",
}
```

The json string could have different number of key-val pairs every time, so there is no static count as such to measure number of lines in json command.

Here is how C# client sends json string to java server

```
        String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map, Formatting.Indented);            
        streamWriter.WriteLine(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
```

I want to read json this in the java code written in android. it looks something like as shown below, **it reads the json lines properly but it blocks after reading last line of json command** I am not sure what is the decent way to know that command has ended ..

```
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);   
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream inStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();           
        InputStreamReader inStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);          
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inStreamReader );    

        String input = "";                        

        while((input = buffReader.readLine())!= null)
        {
            command += input;                     
        }

             //Does not get to this point, blocks above on the readLine after reading full json..

        JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject(input);
        Object ovj = jsObj.get("command");
```

I know may be I can send number of lines before sending json and read that many times in a while loop ? but that looks like a dirty solution, please advise what's the right way to do it.

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: readLine is giving me one line (part) of json like { for first readLine ..

Comment: Yes you are right, that was it.. Formatting.Indented was the problem. Thanks. I will accept it as answer if you post one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove `Formatting.Indented`, every `buffReader.readLine()` will return you a different(complete) json. Move your deserialization code into the while loop.

Comment: thank you, worked for me :) as a side question, in case I have multiline command, what's best way to read it in full ?

Comment: @Ahmed Better, don't use multiline command. Put all command in a single json object(maybe a command array)

Comment: If you have to process multi-line JSON you could count the curly brackets ++ for every { and -- for every } if your count is 0 and you actually have data then you have a complete message.

Comment: @OmarKooheji In a general case ,counting *curly brackets* is not enough. It can be a json array like `[{...}{...}\n]`