# Exchanging Objects between Android and C#

Tags: c#, android, sockets, object

Is there a build-in posibility to exchange(send and receive) objects (objects consist of other objects and standard datatypes: arrays, strings, integers, doubles) between Android clients and a C#.NET server over Sockets?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. JSON looks like what I needs. As far as I understand the following needs to happen: 1. Open a connection 2. Get an object and serialize (to json) it then send it over this connection and deserialize it there into an object again?

Comment: this is similar to what you described, may be worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192955/reading-json-string-from-socket

Comment: and yes that's the idea